# How to mock FileSystemDatasetFactory Class

Tags: mocking

Iam using Junit and PowerMockito.How can i mock below FileSystemDatasetFactory method call?

```
Schema getFileSchema(String uri,FileFormat format){
DatasetFactory factory = new FileSystemDatasetFactory(allocator,
                NativeMemoryPool.getDefault(), format, uri);
return factory.inspect();
}


@Test
Public void testGetFileSchema(){
FileSystemDatasetFactory fileSystemDatasetFactory =mock(FileSystemDatasetFactory.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(FileSystemDatasetFactory.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(fileSystemDatasetFactory)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to mock FileSystemDatasetFactory Class?